# Query where timestamp field is older than another timestamp field in MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I obtain an object from a MongoDB collection where a specific field1 (timestamp or date) is older/newer than another specific field2 (timestamp or date)?

Given the following example object:

```
// MongoDB 3.2
{
  name: 'test',
  updated_on: Timestamp(1474416000, 0),
  export: {
    active: true,
    last_exported_on: Timestamp(1474329600, 0)
  }
}
```

This object should match a query like: `where export.active is true and updated_on > export.last_exported_on`

I've tried it with the aggregation framework, since I've read that $where can be very slow, but without any success.

```
// PHP 5.4 (and MongoDB PHP lib. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library)
$collection->aggregate([
  ['$project' => [
    'dst' => ['$cmp' => ['updated_on', 'export.last_exported_on']],
    'name' => true
  ]],
  ['$match' => ['dst' => ['$gt' => 0], 'export.active' => ['$eq' => true]]],
  ['$limit' => 1]
]);
```

I can change timestamps into date or anything else, but I don't see the problem in the type.

Edit: Not all objects have the `last_exported_on` or the `export` fields at all. Besides that both can be null or empty or 000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because after you do the `$project` you end up only with the `dst` and `_id` fields, so you cannot `$match` on `export.active`. You need to match on `export.active` before the projection. After that you need another match on the `dst` field.

```
[
    {
        $match: {
            "export.active": true
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            dst: {
                $cmp: [
                    "$updated_on",
                    "$export.last_exported_on"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            dst: 1
        }
    }
]
```

#### Edit

Alternatively, you can make sure to preserve `export.active` and to spare another `$match`:

```
[
    {
        $project: {
            "export.active": 1,
            cmp: {
                $cmp: [
                    "$updated_on",
                    "$export.last_exported_on"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            cmp: 1,
            "export.active": true
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you. Besides my wrong order of the pipe/not preserving the `export.active` for the match, I've used `updated_on` instead of `$updated_on` etc.